# How to determine and specify facebook fql timestamp

Tags: facebook, datetime, timestamp, facebook-fql, unix-timestamp

I've been querying **stream** table to search for a post that was published a few months back with this query:

```
SELECT post_id, message  FROM stream WHERE source_id=group_ID and actor_id=USER_ID
```

However, it's not returning any result because the post's publication date is not current. So I've wanted to specify the **updated_time** field in this table.

What would be the correct value for **updated_time** if I want it to be not less than 3 months back?

say, **updated_time < now() and updated_time > 3_months_before**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updated_time` is the [**UNIX timestamp**](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

**In PHP** you can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/function.strtotime)-

```
strtotime("-3 month") //3 months ago
strtotime("now") //now
```

In **Javascript**-

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000); //3 months ago

Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); //now
```